# interface and implementation C++

Tags: c++, interface, compiler-errors

I'm writing a code to separate interface and it's implementation but it has an error, I followed the correct syntax of interfaces and classes ,I have seen many examples on this subject, Knowing I'm a former C# programmer.

code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <String>
using namespace std;

            ///////////////////EMPLOYEE CLASS AND INTERFACE //////////////
class Interface_Employee
{

public:
    Interface_Employee() {}
    virtual ~Interface_Employee() {}
    virtual void print() = 0;    // "= 0" part makes this method pure virtual, and
                                 // also makes this class abstract.
};

class Employee : public Interface_Employee
{
    int ID, Age;
    Bank ac1, ac2; //composition
public:
    Employee(int a, int b, Bank account1, Bank account2)
        : ac1(account1), ac2(account2)
    {
        ID = a; Age = b;
    }
    ~Employee() {}


    // Provide implementation for the first method

    void print()
    {
        cout << "Age is:/n" << Age << "ID is:" << ID;
        ac1.print();
        ac2.print();
    }
};
                 ////////////BANK CLASS AND INTERFACE//////////////////


      class Interface_Bank
      {
          public:
          Interface_Bank() {}
          virtual ~Interface_Bank() {}
          virtual void print() = 0;    // "= 0" part makes this method pure virtual, and
                               // also makes this class abstract.
      };

      class Bank : public Interface_Bank
      {
        private:
        int balance, ID;

        public:
        Bank(int a, int b)
        {
          balance = a;
          ID = b;
        }
        ~Bank() {}

     // Provide implementation for the first method
        void print()
            {
              cout << "Balance is:/n" << balance << "ID is:" << ID;
            }


           };

        class Output {

           int main(void)
            {
            Bank a(1000, 1);
            Bank b(2000, 2);
            Employee c(2, 25, a, b);

            return 0;
           }

          };
```

Error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3646   ***'ac1': unknown override specifier*** console_App c:\users\dell_alrfou\source\repos\console_app\console_app\console_app.cpp   22
Error   C2059   ***syntax error: ','*** console_App c:\users\dell_alrfou\source\repos\console_app\console_app\console_app.cpp   22
Error   C2238   ***unexpected token(s) preceding ';'*** console_App c:\users\dell_alrfou\source\repos\console_app\console_app\console_app.cpp   22
Error   ***C2061    syntax error: identifier 'Bank'***  console_App c:\users\dell_alrfou\source\repos\console_app\console_app\console_app.cpp   24
Error   C2065   ***'account1': undeclared identifier*** console_App c:\users\dell_alrfou\source\repos\console_app\console_app\console_app.cpp   25
Error   C2065   ***'account2': undeclared identifier*** console_App c:\users\dell_alrfou\source\repos\console_app\console_app\console_app.cpp   25
Error   C2614   ***'Employee': illegal member initialization: 'ac1' is not a base or member***  console_App c:\users\dell_alrfou\source\repos\console_app\console_app\console_app.cpp   25
Error   C2614   ***'Employee': illegal member initialization: 'ac2' is not a base or member***  console_App c:\users\dell_alrfou\source\repos\console_app\console_app\console_app.cpp   25
Error   ***C2065    'ac1': undeclared identifier*** console_App c:\users\dell_alrfou\source\repos\console_app\console_app\console_app.cpp   37
Error   C2228   ***left of '.print' must have class/struct/union*** console_App c:\users\dell_alrfou\source\repos\console_app\console_app\console_app.cpp   37
Error   C2065   ***'ac2': undeclared identifier***  console_App c:\users\dell_alrfou\source\repos\console_app\console_app\console_app.cpp   38
Error   C2228   ***left of '.print' must have class/struct/union*** console_App c:\users\dell_alrfou\source\repos\console_app\console_app\console_app.cpp   38
Error   C2661   **'Employee::Employee': no overloaded function takes 4 arguments**  console_App c:\users\dell_alrfou\source\repos\console_app\console_app\console_app.cpp   81

Comment: There's no override specifier in the code you have shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Before use `Bank`, you should declare or define it
2. `int main()` shouldn't in a `class`

The following `code` could work:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <String>
using namespace std;

class Interface_Bank
{
public:
    Interface_Bank() {}
    virtual ~Interface_Bank() {}
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Bank : public Interface_Bank
{
private:
    int balance, ID;

public:
    Bank(int a, int b) : balance(a), ID(b)
    {
    }
    ~Bank() {}

    void print()
    {
        cout << "Balance is:/n" << balance << "ID is:" << ID;
    }
};

class Interface_Employee
{
public:
    Interface_Employee() {}
    virtual ~Interface_Employee() {}
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Employee : public Interface_Employee
{
private: 
    int ID, Age;
    Bank ac1, ac2;
public:
    Employee(int a, int b, Bank account1, Bank account2)
        : ID(a), Age(b), ac1(account1), ac2(account2)
    {
    }
    ~Employee() {}

    void print()
    {
        cout << "Age is:/n" << Age << "ID is:" << ID;
        ac1.print();
        ac2.print();
    }
};

int main(void)
{   
    Bank a(1000, 1);
    Bank b(2000, 2);
    Employee c(2, 25, a, b);
    c.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Yunbin Liu for help and for your time

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare or define the `Bank` class before you attempt to use it.

You need to move the definition of `Bank` (and its `Interface_Bank` base class) to before `class Employee`.